# How do capacitors work?

Tags: electricity, electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, electrical-resistance

Say you have a battery, with a wire connecting the negative and positive terminal. Initially, (the transient state) the electric field is not uniform and is perpendicular to the surface of the cross section of the wire.

This forces the surface charges to rearrange, and the surface charges keep moving until the electric field in the wire is uniform and at any point, the electric field is perpendicular to the cross section of the wire at that point. This is the steady state, and is when current is flowing.

Now consider a circuit that consists of a battery and a capacitor connected to the both the terminals. Could someone walk me through how the capacitor is charged using the concepts of surface charge redistribution discussed above?

**Please note I am not looking for a general explanation, I'm looking for an explanation that shows how the surface charges redistributing themselves during the transient state to ensure the electric field is perpendicular to the wire results in the capacitor charging.**

Comment: The first three Google results have more than satisfactory explanations. You should check [this](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/capacitor.htm), [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Qwx75eg8w) and [this](http://www.murata.com/products/emicon_fun/2011/01/cap_en14.html?page=3) out

Comment: @PranavHosangadi No, they don't. I'm specifically asking for an explanation that utilizes the concept of surface charge. None of the links do that.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: The youtube video from 00:30 to 00:50 does it pretty well I guess

Comment: @PranavHosangadi What? No it doesn't. Its just an animation of electrons moving. I'm looking for an explanation that shows how the surface charges redistribute themselves during the transient state and how this results in the capacitor charging...

Comment: Electrons moving = surface charge redistribution. That's all there is to a capacitor

Comment: Consider this - electrons get more dense on the plate connected to the negative terminal, and less dense on the positive plate.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The surface charge distributes itself so that the field is always perpendicular to the surface of the wire. How is this result in the capacitor charging?

Comment: dfg, almost any *physical* capacitor is, by virtue of its construction, in essence, an open circuited transmission line.  I'm not interested in "walking you through this".  Take that walk yourself; it will be much more rewarding.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri That's fine, but could you give me a basic explanation and leave the details to me? Because I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days, to no avail. I can't consolidate the concept of the surface charges redistributing to make the electric field perpendicular to the wire with the concept of the capacitor charging to have the same voltage as the battery.

Comment: I'm with @AlfredCentauri on this. This is the same physics that you get in any other piece of conductor, which means that the details are *tedious and boring* unless you can motivate the desire for a detailed microscopic analysis of this geometry in terms of something interesting to be learned from it. Nor does the pure number of questions you have asked on the same physics help. I imagine that people would like you to generalize what you have been taught so far; take some responsibility for running with it.

Comment: @dmckee Believe me, I've tried. Sorry if it feels like I'm just asking you for the answer without putting in any effort of my own. I'm only asking because I've struggled with this for a while, even after going over the answers you have already given (which I really do appreciate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially when you attach the capacitor to the battery, said battery will act to create an electric field within the wire. On the side of the negative terminal this field will point perpendicular to the cross section of the wire toward the terminal of the battery (electric field points toward negative charge). On the side of the positive terminal the field will point perpendicular to the cross section of the wire away from the terminal of the battery. This is because the battery arranges the electric charge in such a way that the negative terminal is electron rich and the positive is electron deficient.

Now, this electric field will cause charges to move. On the side of the negative terminal, the electric field will push the electrons away from the battery and toward one side of the capacitor. On the side of the positive terminal, the field will pull electrons from the capacitor and toward the battery. When this happens we see that the side of the capacitor attached to the negative terminal of the battery is accumulating electrons (becoming negative), and the side of the capacitor attached to the positive terminal of the battery is losing electrons (becoming positive). But what is this motion of charges doing to the field? 
With electrons accumulating on the negative side of the capacitor, the field within the wire is decreasing (because now there is less of a potential difference between the negative terminal of the battery and the negative side of the capacitor due to the accumulation of the charges). Electrons will continue to be pushed toward the negative side of the capacitor, however, until this field decreases to zero. This will happen when enough charges accumulate on the negative side of the capacitor to bring the negative capacitor plate to the same potential as the negative terminal of the battery. By the same argument, electrons will continue to be pulled away from the positive side of the capacitor until the field is brought to zero when the positive capacitor plate achieves the same potential as the positive terminal of the battery.

From reading the comments above it seemed to me that this is the type of explanation you are, perhaps, looking for. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, the charge builds up on the capacitor to neutralize the field from the battery, resulting in the field in the wire being zero. But there are other possible distributions of charge which causes the field in the wire to be zero.

Comment: For instance, you could have a buildup of charge at the terminals of the battery (positive charge buildup at the negative terminal and negative charge terminal at the positive terminal) - this would also result in the field being zero. So how do we know charge building up on the capacitor plates is always the charge distribution that is created to neutralize the field?

Comment: I didn't mean in the battery, I mean't in the wire - at the edge of the wire that connects to the terminal. I was under the impression that the battery only maintains a negative and positive charge *in* the battery, but doesn't have control over what's outside it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Why would the positive charges be pushed away from the *negative* terminal? The positive charges would only have to overcome the 9V if it was at the positive terminal? Wouldn't it be *attracted* to the negative terminal?

Comment: I see. But then there wouldn't be a problem with the charge building scenario I gave right? Because there would a positive charge buildup at the negative terminal, and negative charge buildup at the positive terminal so no charge would have to overcome any potential. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Ah, I apologize a thousand times, I read your comment incorrectly and was attempting to answer a question you didn't ask. My mistake.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that positive charges accumulate at the negative terminal and negative charges accumulate at the positive terminal. This is actually what I said in my original answer. Positive charges accumulate at the negative terminal, leaving the capacitor plate on that side with excess negative charge. Negative charges accumulate on the positive terminal, leaving the capacitor plate on that side with excess positive charge. Only I answered the question purely in terms of moving electrons, not moving positive and negative charges.

Comment: Ah I see. If there is charge buildup at the terminals, and charge buildup on the capacitor plates, wouldn't the capacitor be at a lower voltage than the battery? Since the field is being brought to zero not only by the capacitor but also by the charge buildup at the terminals, shouldn't the capacitor being charged to less than 9V be enough to neutralize the field?

Comment: In reality, yes. When we say that the potentials are _exactly_ equal we are considering an ideal case where there is no resistance in the wire, so there is a potential of exactly 9V on the positive terminal of the battery and exactly 9V on the positive capacitor plate, with no voltage drop in between, meaning all charges accumulate either completely on the capacitor plate or completely on the terminal of the battery. Technically this is not completely true, but it is a very close approximation.

Comment: Why would there be no buildup in an wire with no resistance? Also, why would this be a good approximation? I see no reason why there would be more charge buildup on the capacitor plates than near the terminals.

Comment: It's a good approximation because a wire has a very very small resistance compared to anything else in the circuit. In a real wire it takes work to "push" charges through the wire, so once they reach the capacitor they are at a slightly lower potential than when they were at the terminal of the battery. Thus, the situation really becomes a whole different question at that point. But in the ideal case we basically assume that all of the charges are accumulating _on_ the terminal and _on_ the capacitor plates, because in the ideal case the wire has no effect on the rest of the circuit.